# How do you run CPU at turbo speed continuously

Tags: centos, cpu, cpu-frequency

```
processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v3 @ 3.30GHz
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 3299.670
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm
bogomips        : 6599.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

I've set the following:

```
title OpenVZ (2.6.32-042stab092.3)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-042stab092.3 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_vpsny23-lv_root intel_pstate=disable nomodeset rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_vpsny23/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_vpsny23/lv_swap nodmraid rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet 
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-042stab092.3.img
```

But it still only shows/runs at 3.30GHz.

Comment: Grab the `i7z` tool, that'll show you the frequency each core is running at and if turbo boost is enabled. Note that its only used when you are pegging core(s).